# How to develop an applicatioon using nodejs and oracledb

Tags: node.js, oracle11g

Recently I learned an application called SqlPad, I try to modify it to make it connect to oracle and execute sql.But I have not make it.

Comment: From the Github page: > A Node.js web app for writing and running SQL queries and visualizing the results. Supports Postgres, MySQL, SQL Server and Vertica.

Comment: There is not enough information here to help you. What have you tried? Can you provide a specific code example (your config)? Are you receiving any errors?

Answer (score 0):

Have you submitted any SqlPad pull requests to resolve https://github.com/rickbergfalk/sqlpad/issues/21 ?